# check if element is user visible using boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, position, offset

I've gone through a lot of solutions on stackoverflow to check if an element is currently visible in the user's pane but none of them seem to work when using bootstrap.

if the right jsfiddle result screen is big enough to display the right column, then a 'OK' alert is displayed. But if the right column goes below the fold, then I don't get any alert when the user scrolls to where the element is.

https://jsfiddle.net/play75010/xjuj49kr/5/

Here I'm using checkVisible() found on stackoverflow but I've checked it with many other solutions.

Any idea ?

```
function checkVisible( elm, evalType ) {
    evalType = evalType || "visible";

var vpH = $(window).height(), // Viewport Height
    st = $(window).scrollTop(), // Scroll Top
    y = $(elm).offset().top,
    elementHeight = $(elm).height();

if (evalType === "visible") return ((y < (vpH + st)) && (y > (st - elementHeight)));
if (evalType === "above") return ((y < (vpH + st)));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to check on scroll might be what you're looking for:

```
  $(window).scroll( function() {
      update();   
      console.log('fire');
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xjuj49kr/8/)